# Eclipse Add Custom Icon to content type

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-pde

I have defined a custom Content-type at the extension point : **org.eclipse.core.contenttypes.contentTypes**

Now i want to add a custom icon to the specific file type, but i cant seem to find the extension point.
Am i just not finding the right point, or is this the wrong approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The icon is actually for the editor registered for the content type rather than the content type directly.

It is declared by the `icon` attribute of the `org.eclipse.ui.editors` extension point of the editor with a matching content type binding (or using the `extensions` attribute.

Comment: Oh okay. Thanks!